# Extract all <li> elements from tag with certain class name

Tags: html, web-scraping, xpath

Probably the title of my question seems to be ambiguous, since I am not familiar with glossary of html terms. Suppose I want to find a tag, with particular attribute name. In my case I am looking for tag  that contains **data-scroll-id** with particular name that contains "requirements":

```
data-scroll-id="requirements-1"
data-scroll-id="requirements-expected"
data-scroll-id="requirements-main-2"
```

For this purpose I use following xpath construction (it works):
`//*[contains(@data-scroll-id, 'requirements')]` 
The problem is that I want to extract `<li>` elements of particular  tags as a separate elements/list of element (As on image below). Each `<li>` tag contain specific information I want to extract. I cannot access to this `<li>` tags using class name since from page to page their class name my differ, so I need to find parent element with constant class name for instance. In my case I chose `data-scroll-id="requirements-1"` (As on image below). Moreover, the number of  tags inside my "main"  tags may differ to from 1 to N.

**Question**: How can I extract child `<li>` tags knowing attribute name of parent  tag (as on image below).

[image]

Comment: Please give us the URL of the website, so we have example data to work on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find all `li` elements anywhere within a `div` having `data-scroll-id` of `requirements-1` use:

```
//div[@data-scroll-id="requirements-1"]//li
```

If it is not always a div or the value is not always exactly "requirements-1", then you can use a predicate similar to your original example to locate `li` elements anywhere within an element having attribute `data-scroll-id` containing text `requirements`:

```
//*[contains(@data-scroll-id,"requirements")]//li
```

Or if the value is always "requirements-1":

```
//*[@data-scroll-id = "requirements-1"]//li
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery

```
quotes = []; 
$('div[data-scroll-id="requirements-1"]').each(function() {
    var quote = {
      'li': $(this).find('li[class="OfferView1ehZBj"]').text(), 
    }
    quotes.push(quote);
    console.log(quote);
});
```